# Browser resizing and menu bar issue

Tags: wordpress, menubar

http://playoutthegame.com/

Whenever the browser width is decreased from maximum, the elements of the menu bar overlap the logo. As the browser width is further decreased, the menu bar disappears before reappearing as a drop-down menu. Can the menu bar be made to not overlap the site logo during resize? And is there a way to ensure that the menu bar remains visible, without a gap during its transition from bar menu to drop-down menu?

Theme is enfold. http://themeforest.net/item/enfold-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4519990

Comment: Is your site using a child theme and if so, are you using the latest version of Enfold? They update regularly.

Comment: The site in the link you provided seems to be considerably different from the example on themeforest in regards to how the menu functions. Did you make modifications?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this with Enfold a number of times.

I tend to use CSS media queries to change an appropriate combination of padding between menu items, letter-spacing and font-size so that you cn reduce screen width without overlapping. If I have a lot of items in the menu and you have less space to play with, I usually also change the mobile menu settings in the theme options to break at 989px instead of 768px (in the latest version of the theme, this is at Enfold > Main Menu > Menu Items for mobile).

The CSS you need will be something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.av-main-nav > .menu-item > a {
    padding: 0 7px;
}
.av-main-nav > .menu-item > a .avia-menu-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px {
...etc
```

Not sure why it disappears at any stage. Would need to see the site to reproduce it. The site you've posted is a shopify site.